# get bytearraycontent in web service

Tags: c#, web-services, asmx, multipart

I'm trying to parse an image to a byte array and send it to my web service. Problem is, I couldn't find any way to read the bytearraycontent (in the past I have used HttpContext.Current.Request.Files but obviously it isn't there)... any help please?

EDIT - I managed to get the added form data but it won't save the image properly. I switches to stringContent and it still doesn't work, the received string is exactly the same size as the string I sent and yet it can't open it. Added ' requestValidationMode="2.0" ' in web.config.

code:

```
public async Task uploadAP()
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        MultipartFormDataContent form = new MultipartFormDataContent();
        string str = File.ReadAllText(DEBRIS_PIC_PATH);
                form.Add(new StringContent(str), "ap");
                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("http://192.168.1.10:8080/WS.asmx/uploadAP", form);
    }
}
```

and obviously something like:

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]
public void uploadAP()
{
    string t = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["ap"];     
    FileStream objfilestream = new FileStream(debrisApPath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
    objfilestream.Write(binaryWriteArray, 0, binaryWriteArray.Length);
    objfilestream.Close();
}
```

Comment: The image I want to send, doesn't really matter... it's a pictureBox

Comment: ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF or ASP.NET Web API should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Comment: Have you tried adding a MultipartFormDataClient as a parameter to your service method, then just try to access the ByteArrayContent from there?

Comment: @DavidW: thank you for the comment, but what do you mean? how will I send it as a parameter? can you attach a link to an example?

Comment: @JohnSaunders: thank you, that is definitely informative, but... this is ASP.NET, a web application... what do you mean?

Comment: `[WebMethod]` is in which file? Something.asmx? That's an old ASMX web service. That's a legacy technology, and should not be  used for new development.

Comment: You wouldn't send it; the framework would send it by virtue of your calling it via PostAsync. Just modify your server-side function to read "public void uploadAP(MultipartFormDataClient formData){} and see if you can access the content within the formData variable.

Comment: Microsoft has essentially retired the ASMX-based web service methodology. They've replaced it with WCF (Windows Communication Framework) and the new WebAPI. If you are developing this from scratch, it might be worthwhile to explore this for your project. Think it might simplify things for you.

Comment: @DavidW: MultipartFormDataClient is not a recognized class... did you mean MultipartFormDataContent? and how will I get the byte array from it?

Comment: Let me sketch up a reply and post it as an answer. Hopefully if I get a few things wrong I won't get toooo many brickbats :)

Comment: @DavidW: sorry to bother, but...?

Comment: Sorry..got called away...will try to get back to this today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apologies for the delay. Here is an example I promised with old-style ASMX web service that will read `ByteArrayContent` from a client, following which I will offer two caveats...

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.ServiceModel.Activation;
namespace OldWSTest
{
   /// <summary>
   /// Summary description for Service1
   /// </summary>
   [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
   [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
   [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
   [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Required)]
   public class Service1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
   {

      [WebMethod]
      public string uploadAP()
      {
         var foo = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["ap"];

         byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(foo);
         // do whatever you need with the bytes here
         return "done";
      }
   }
}
```

1. I surely echo John Saunders' comments that, for ground-up web service work, a project like this should take a good, hard look at WCF/WebAPI, not ASMX. I had forgotten what a pain ASMX-based web services could be.
2. I *won't* promise this is the **ideal** way to get this data on the web service side; there are almost surely more elegant/efficient/better/slicker/faster ways to do it. I kept finding roadblocks that I think are tied to the limitations of the old-style web service model. This, however, as best I can test, works"
3. The `AspNetCompatibilityRequirements` mode allowed me to access the Form collection, whereas without it, it wasn't available at all without parsing/drilling into the boundary data.

Good luck. I hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, first thing - thank you so much for your answer! second - what about those attributes you used? [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)] and  [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]? Should I copy those?

Comment: I can't find any of the attributes, but hold on - you're telling me that it just adds it to the form data? that's odd, I couldn't find it in the Form!

Comment: I would. That's I posted the whole sample source code, including the usings, so you could see where everything comes from 

Comment: Sorry for going full retard, but - it seems to be working without it but it's giving me a 'dangerous content' exception... should I use unsafe? (I know that it doesn't make a lot of sense but who knows?)

Comment: Nevermind, found requestValidationMode="2.0", but it still doesn't work. Could you please take a look at the update?

Comment: Hi @FitzChivalry - Are you getting the binary bytes for the file in the server side with the code I provided? I used your client source virtually untouched, but just sent an array of nine bytes up (rather than an image file). The web service extracted those nine bytes on the money. As a test, change your client to just send up a small byte array and get that to your web service code; once that works, extending it to a large binary image file should be no problem.